# Upgrading Laravel 5.5 to 5.6 error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.6

I am trying to upgrade my Laravel `5.5` to `5.6.` I have followed the instructions from the [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade) website, yet I got this error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
    Problem 1
        - The requested package laravel/framework 5.6.* is satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.6.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

So, I changed my `composer.json` file and added 2 lines: `**"minimum-stability": "dev", "prefer-stable": true,**` based on the first answer on [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/need-help-with-composer-minimum-stability) laracast discussion.

Everything seemed to be working just fine until I got another error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 6 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating sebastian/diff (2.0.1 => 3.0.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Updating phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (5.0.6 => 6.0.0): Downloading (100%)    - Updating phpunit/php-timer (1.0.9 => 2.0.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Updating phpunit/php-token-stream (2.0.2 => 3.0.0): Downloading (100%)        - Updating phpunit/php-code-coverage (5.3.0 => 6.0.1): Downloading (100%)       - Updating phpunit/phpunit (6.5.6 => 7.0.0): Downloading (100%)         
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover

In trustedproxy.php line 66:

  Undefined class constant 'HEADER_CLIENT_IP'  


Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

The problem on line 66 is **Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_CLIENT_IP    => 'X_FORWARDED_FOR',**.
I have searched other posts on stackoverflow but still no luck. The last thing I tried was composer selfupdate and composer global update which was mentioned on the post [composer dump-autoload not recognized command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47645045/composer-dump-autoload-not-recognized-command)

Also, I cannot remove "minimum-stability": "dev","prefer-stable": true because if I do, then I will get the following error:

```
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.6.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.6.x-dev].
- Removal request for laravel/framework == 5.6.9999999.9999999-dev
```

I have attached my composer.json file and trustedproxy.php respectively. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0",
        "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

trustedproxy.php `(error in line 66--> Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_CLIENT_IP    => 'X_FORWARDED_FOR',)`

```
<?php

return [

    /*
     * Set trusted proxy IP addresses.
     *
     * Both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses are
     * supported, along with CIDR notation.
     *
     * The "*" character is syntactic sugar
     * within TrustedProxy to trust any proxy
     * that connects directly to your server,
     * a requirement when you cannot know the address
     * of your proxy (e.g. if using Rackspace balancers).
     *
     * The "**" character is syntactic sugar within
     * TrustedProxy to trust not just any proxy that
     * connects directly to your server, but also
     * proxies that connect to those proxies, and all
     * the way back until you reach the original source
     * IP. It will mean that $request->getClientIp()
     * always gets the originating client IP, no matter
     * how many proxies that client's request has
     * subsequently passed through.
     */
    'proxies' => [
        '192.168.1.10',
    ],

    /*
     * Or, to trust all proxies that connect
     * directly to your server, uncomment this:
     */
     # 'proxies' => '*',

    /*
     * Or, to trust ALL proxies, including those that
     * are in a chain of forwarding, uncomment this:
    */
    # 'proxies' => '**',

    /*
     * Default Header Names
     *
     * Change these if the proxy does
     * not send the default header names.
     *
     * Note that headers such as X-Forwarded-For
     * are transformed to HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR format.
     *
     * The following are Symfony defaults, found in
     * \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::$trustedHeaders
     *
     * You may optionally set headers to 'null' here if you'd like
     * for them to be considered untrusted instead. Ex:
     *
     * Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_CLIENT_HOST  => null,
     * 
     * WARNING: If you're using AWS Elastic Load Balancing or Heroku,
     * the FORWARDED and X_FORWARDED_HOST headers should be set to null 
     * as they are currently unsupported there.
     */
    'headers' => [
        (defined('Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_FORWARDED') ? Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_FORWARDED : 'forwarded') => 'FORWARDED',
        Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_CLIENT_IP    => 'X_FORWARDED_FOR',
        Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_CLIENT_HOST  => 'X_FORWARDED_HOST',
        Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_CLIENT_PROTO => 'X_FORWARDED_PROTO',
        Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_CLIENT_PORT  => 'X_FORWARDED_PORT',
    ]
];
```

Illuminate\Http\Request file:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Http;

use Closure;
use ArrayAccess;
use RuntimeException;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request as SymfonyRequest;

class Request extends SymfonyRequest implements Arrayable, ArrayAccess
{
    use Concerns\InteractsWithContentTypes,
        Concerns\InteractsWithFlashData,
        Concerns\InteractsWithInput,
        Macroable;

    /**
     * The decoded JSON content for the request.
     *
     * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag|null
     */
    protected $json;

    /**
     * All of the converted files for the request.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $convertedFiles;

    /**
     * The user resolver callback.
     *
     * @var \Closure
     */
    protected $userResolver;

    /**
     * The route resolver callback.
     *
     * @var \Closure
     */
    protected $routeResolver;

    /**
     * Create a new Illuminate HTTP request from server variables.
     *
     * @return static
     */
    public static function capture()
    {
        static::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();

        return static::createFromBase(SymfonyRequest::createFromGlobals());
    }

    /**
     * Return the Request instance.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function instance()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the request method.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function method()
    {
        return $this->getMethod();
    }

    /**
     * Get the root URL for the application.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function root()
    {
        return rtrim($this->getSchemeAndHttpHost().$this->getBaseUrl(), '/');
    }

    /**
     * Get the URL (no query string) for the request.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function url()
    {
        return rtrim(preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $this->getUri()), '/');
    }

    /**
     * Get the full URL for the request.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function fullUrl()
    {
        $query = $this->getQueryString();

        $question = $this->getBaseUrl().$this->getPathInfo() == '/' ? '/?' : '?';

        return $query ? $this->url().$question.$query : $this->url();
    }

    /**
     * Get the full URL for the request with the added query string parameters.
     *
     * @param  array  $query
     * @return string
     */
    public function fullUrlWithQuery(array $query)
    {
        $question = $this->getBaseUrl().$this->getPathInfo() == '/' ? '/?' : '?';

        return count($this->query()) > 0
            ? $this->url().$question.http_build_query(array_merge($this->query(), $query))
            : $this->fullUrl().$question.http_build_query($query);
    }

    /**
     * Get the current path info for the request.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function path()
    {
        $pattern = trim($this->getPathInfo(), '/');

        return $pattern == '' ? '/' : $pattern;
    }

    /**
     * Get the current decoded path info for the request.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function decodedPath()
    {
        return rawurldecode($this->path());
    }

    /**
     * Get a segment from the URI (1 based index).
     *
     * @param  int  $index
     * @param  string|null  $default
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function segment($index, $default = null)
    {
        return Arr::get($this->segments(), $index - 1, $default);
    }

    /**
     * Get all of the segments for the request path.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function segments()
    {
        $segments = explode('/', $this->decodedPath());

        return array_values(array_filter($segments, function ($value) {
            return $value !== '';
        }));
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the current request URI matches a pattern.
     *
     * @param  dynamic  $patterns
     * @return bool
     */
    public function is(...$patterns)
    {
        foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
            if (Str::is($pattern, $this->decodedPath())) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the route name matches a given pattern.
     *
     * @param  dynamic  $patterns
     * @return bool
     */
    public function routeIs(...$patterns)
    {
        return $this->route() && $this->route()->named(...$patterns);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the current request URL and query string matches a pattern.
     *
     * @param  dynamic  $patterns
     * @return bool
     */
    public function fullUrlIs(...$patterns)
    {
        $url = $this->fullUrl();

        foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
            if (Str::is($pattern, $url)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the request is the result of an AJAX call.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function ajax()
    {
        return $this->isXmlHttpRequest();
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the request is the result of an PJAX call.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function pjax()
    {
        return $this->headers->get('X-PJAX') == true;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the request is over HTTPS.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function secure()
    {
        return $this->isSecure();
    }

    /**
     * Get the client IP address.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function ip()
    {
        return $this->getClientIp();
    }

    /**
     * Get the client IP addresses.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function ips()
    {
        return $this->getClientIps();
    }

    /**
     * Get the client user agent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function userAgent()
    {
        return $this->headers->get('User-Agent');
    }

    /**
     * Merge new input into the current request's input array.
     *
     * @param  array  $input
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Request
     */
    public function merge(array $input)
    {
        $this->getInputSource()->add($input);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Replace the input for the current request.
     *
     * @param  array  $input
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Request
     */
    public function replace(array $input)
    {
        $this->getInputSource()->replace($input);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the JSON payload for the request.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed   $default
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag|mixed
     */
    public function json($key = null, $default = null)
    {
        if (! isset($this->json)) {
            $this->json = new ParameterBag((array) json_decode($this->getContent(), true));
        }

        if (is_null($key)) {
            return $this->json;
        }

        return data_get($this->json->all(), $key, $default);
    }

    /**
     * Get the input source for the request.
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag
     */
    protected function getInputSource()
    {
        if ($this->isJson()) {
            return $this->json();
        }

        return $this->getRealMethod() == 'GET' ? $this->query : $this->request;
    }

    /**
     * Create an Illuminate request from a Symfony instance.
     *
     * @param  \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Request
     */
    public static function createFromBase(SymfonyRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request instanceof static) {
            return $request;
        }

        $content = $request->content;

        $request = (new static)->duplicate(
            $request->query->all(), $request->request->all(), $request->attributes->all(),
            $request->cookies->all(), $request->files->all(), $request->server->all()
        );

        $request->content = $content;

        $request->request = $request->getInputSource();

        return $request;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function duplicate(array $query = null, array $request = null, array $attributes = null, array $cookies = null, array $files = null, array $server = null)
    {
        return parent::duplicate($query, $request, $attributes, $cookies, $this->filterFiles($files), $server);
    }

    /**
     * Filter the given array of files, removing any empty values.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $files
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function filterFiles($files)
    {
        if (! $files) {
            return;
        }

        foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
            if (is_array($file)) {
                $files[$key] = $this->filterFiles($files[$key]);
            }

            if (empty($files[$key])) {
                unset($files[$key]);
            }
        }

        return $files;
    }

    /**
     * Get the session associated with the request.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Session\Store
     *
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     */
    public function session()
    {
        if (! $this->hasSession()) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Session store not set on request.');
        }

        return $this->session;
    }

    /**
     * Get the session associated with the request.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Session\Store|null
     */
    public function getSession()
    {
        return $this->session;
    }

    /**
     * Set the session instance on the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Session\Session  $session
     * @return void
     */
    public function setLaravelSession($session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * Get the user making the request.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function user($guard = null)
    {
        return call_user_func($this->getUserResolver(), $guard);
    }

    /**
     * Get the route handling the request.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $param
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Route|object|string
     */
    public function route($param = null)
    {
        $route = call_user_func($this->getRouteResolver());

        if (is_null($route) || is_null($param)) {
            return $route;
        }

        return $route->parameter($param);
    }

    /**
     * Get a unique fingerprint for the request / route / IP address.
     *
     * @return string
     *
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     */
    public function fingerprint()
    {
        if (! $route = $this->route()) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Unable to generate fingerprint. Route unavailable.');
        }

        return sha1(implode('|', array_merge(
            $route->methods(), [$route->getDomain(), $route->uri(), $this->ip()]
        )));
    }

    /**
     * Set the JSON payload for the request.
     *
     * @param  \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag  $json
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setJson($json)
    {
        $this->json = $json;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the user resolver callback.
     *
     * @return \Closure
     */
    public function getUserResolver()
    {
        return $this->userResolver ?: function () {
            //
        };
    }

    /**
     * Set the user resolver callback.
     *
     * @param  \Closure  $callback
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setUserResolver(Closure $callback)
    {
        $this->userResolver = $callback;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the route resolver callback.
     *
     * @return \Closure
     */
    public function getRouteResolver()
    {
        return $this->routeResolver ?: function () {
            //
        };
    }

    /**
     * Set the route resolver callback.
     *
     * @param  \Closure  $callback
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setRouteResolver(Closure $callback)
    {
        $this->routeResolver = $callback;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get all of the input and files for the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        return $this->all();
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the given offset exists.
     *
     * @param  string  $offset
     * @return bool
     */
    public function offsetExists($offset)
    {
        return array_key_exists(
            $offset, $this->all() + $this->route()->parameters()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the value at the given offset.
     *
     * @param  string  $offset
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function offsetGet($offset)
    {
        return $this->__get($offset);
    }

    /**
     * Set the value at the given offset.
     *
     * @param  string  $offset
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function offsetSet($offset, $value)
    {
        $this->getInputSource()->set($offset, $value);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the value at the given offset.
     *
     * @param  string  $offset
     * @return void
     */
    public function offsetUnset($offset)
    {
        $this->getInputSource()->remove($offset);
    }

    /**
     * Check if an input element is set on the request.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @return bool
     */
    public function __isset($key)
    {
        return ! is_null($this->__get($key));
    }

    /**
     * Get an input element from the request.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __get($key)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $this->all())) {
            return data_get($this->all(), $key);
        }

        return $this->route($key);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I actually did and it isn't there. I didn't want to add or change anything because I was afraid I would break something.

Comment: this maybe helpful for update laravel 5.5 to 5.7 or 5.8 [https://stackoverflow.com/a/56556264/8486565](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56556264/8486565)

Answer (score 56):

I did this and it works perfectly.

**1. composer.json:**

**From:**

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
    },
```

**To:**

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
    },
```

**2. Replace app\Http\Middleware\TrustedProxies.php file with contents below:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;

class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The trusted proxies for this application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $proxies;

    /**
     * The headers that should be used to detect proxies.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
}
```

**3. composer update**

Comment: That `"fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",` did the trick. Can't find it in the Upgrade Guide https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade – Rest can be found in the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0" is mentioned in the first line @ `Updating Dependencies`.

Comment: @Robert maybe it was added later, just saying :)

Comment: I had to do "4.0" rather than "~4.0" otherwise composer did not actually update it.

Comment: Any solution for `Declaration of Illuminate\Support\Carbon::__set_state(array $array) should be compatible with Carbon\Carbon::__set_state($state)` ?

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: This error can occur if you forget to update the `config/trustedproxy.php` configuration file via `php artisan vendor:publish` after updating your Composer dependencies. Note also that this command will not overwrite existing configuration files, so you either need to delete the old one before running the Artisan command, or more dangerously, use the `--force` switch for the command (this can cause config files that you've modified to be overwritten with different or default content).

Answer (score 40):

Laravel's Request object extends Symfony's Request object. Laravel 5.5 depends on Symfony 3, which has that constant. Laravel 5.6 depends on Symfony 4, which does not have that constant.

Based on your trusted proxies configuration, it looks like you're using the trusted proxies package "outside" of Laravel. Laravel brought the trusted proxies package inside the framework in 5.5, and created a dedicated `\App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies` middleware for you to use.

I would suggest moving to use the middleware and configuring it as described in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies). This will help prevent this type of compatibility issue in the future.

To make the switch:

1. In `app/Http/Kernel.php`, if `\Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies::class` is in your `$middleware` array, remove it. If `\App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class` is not in your `$middleware` array, add it.
2. Open your `app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php` file and update it with your proxies.
3. Delete your `config/trustedproxy.php` file.
4. Remove `Fideloper\Proxy\TrustedProxyServiceProvider::class` from your `providers` array in `config/app.php`.
5. Update your composer.json file to use "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0". Run `composer update fideloper/proxy` to update the package.

Comment: and what about this `use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;`

Comment: Please use tag 4.0+ for Laravel 5.6:
`composer require fideloper/proxy:~4.0`
[proxy@4](https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy/tree/develop)

Answer (score 10):

I have updated from 5.5 to 5.6

composer.json

```
"minimum-stability":"dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
```

This will install latest Laravel packages, then there will be issue with `TrustedProxies`.

Install the latest proxy version for Laravel 5.6.

Please use tag 4.0+ for Laravel 5.6:

```
composer require fideloper/proxy:~4.0
```

[More details](https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy/tree/develop)

Comment: If I were to remove those 2 lines form my composer.json, how should I proceed? When I tried to update to 5.6 without them I got the first error shown in my post

Comment: You need to add these 2 lines to composer.json, I tried without these lines, but it didn't work. `"minimum-stability":"dev"` will update most of the packages to unstable versions, but this `"prefer-stable":true`, will download stable versions, in my case, except laravel, dusk and passport, all packages are stable, and i got dev versions for latavel and other two.

Answer (score 5):

First install **Laravel 5.6** i faced this error as well.
Just follow the few steps below will fix it:

- Make sure your file `composer.json` requirement has:

```
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
            },
```

- Then try `composer update` to make sure your composer is up-to-date
- Finally run: `composer require fideloper/proxy:~4.0`
- Done!

Answer (score 5):

To anyone who tried upgrading directly from laravel 5.5 to 5.7, and got this problem too, remove the trustedproxy.php file from `app->config->trustedproxy.php`.
Hopes that helps someone.

Comment: I just wanna say a huge THANK YOU for this!!! I couldn't seem to get rid of the error.

Comment: I am glad it helped you.

Comment: this seems to be the only solution that worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Just need to Change fideloper/proxy in composer.json file:-

Your composer.json file now:-

```
"fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
```

Change it to ^4.0 somthing like this:-

```
"fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
```

After that you need to run update composer that's it.

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem comes from your use of the library [TrustedProxy](https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy).

It uses Symfony's `HEADER_CLIENT_IP` constant which was *deprecated* with Symfony 3.3 and completely removed in Symfony 4.0.

Since Laravel 5.6 has updated to use Symfony 4 components, this will no longer work.

The way to solve it is to **[do what patricus suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48595052/4569506)** and use Laravel's TrustProxies middleware.

Comment: Daniel, how can I fix that? Can I just remove them?

Answer (score 2):

I did the following things and got my project to run on Laravel 5.6-dev:

- Followed what **[patricus
  suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48595052/4569506)**
- Changed fideloper/proxy to "~4.0", and added `"minimum-stability":
  "dev", "prefer-stable": true` at the end of my composer.json file.

Answer (score 2):

Replace app\Http\Middleware\TrustedProxies.php by:

```
    <?php

  namespace App\Http\Middleware;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;

  class TrustProxies extends Middleware
  {
    protected $proxies;
    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
  }
```

Replace config\trustedproxy.php by:

```
<?php

return [
    'proxies' => null,
    'headers' => Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL,  
];
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the suggestions here worked for me for some reason.  I am using quickadmin panel and various dependencies which might have something to do with it.

What finally worked was removing laravel/dusk, then updating to `"fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",` on it's own.  Then updating laravel/framework to 5.6, then reinstalling dusk.

I did not need:

`"minimum-stability":"dev",
"prefer-stable": true,`

Maybe that was fixed with recent updates.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue and got a number of guidelines to resolve this. Unfortunately none of those worked or me. Actually there is no additional step or tasks needed to be addressed to fix this issue.

Just follow the official upgrade guide from https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade and along with that remove the `trustedproxy` config file located at `config/trustedproxy.php`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue in Laravel 5.7. You may add `TELESCOPE_ENABLED=false` in your `.env` or `.env.dusk.local` :[Source](https://github.com/laravel/telescope/issues/347#issuecomment-442921310)