# Getting error while updating laravel from 5.5 to 5.7 (Undefined class constant 'HEADER_CLIENT_IP')

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

i am getting this error.

> Undefined class constant 'HEADER_CLIENT_IP' Script @php artisan
>   package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with
>   error code 1

I changed

```
app\Http\Middleware\TrustedProxies.php by:

    <?php

  namespace App\Http\Middleware;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;

  class TrustProxies extends Middleware
  {
    protected $proxies;
    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
  }
```

Here is my .composerjson file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "^0.5.12"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
        "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    } }
```

I am still handling the same error. Can you guys figure it out where the problem is ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At composer.json 
Change fideloper/proxy

From

```
"fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
```

To

```
"fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
```

After that run

```
composer update
```

Comment: For me this didn't help.

Comment: @MiloslavMiloJanoušek, did you get the same error message?

Answer (score 10):

1) change your composer.json to following

```
"php": ">=7.1.3",
"fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
"laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
"laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
```

2) change your App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies.php to following

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;

class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The trusted proxies for this application.
     *
     * @var array|string
     */
    protected $proxies;
    /**
     * The headers that should be used to detect proxies.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
}
```

3) remove the file from the **config** directory having name **trustedproxy.php** if exist

4) run the following command into the console from your application directory

```
composer update
```

5) this step is not necessary but it will clear all cache and autoload files

```
php artisan clear-compiled

composer dump-autoload

php artisan cache:clear

php artisan config:clear

php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: *2)* fixed it for me (I had $headers as array, from previous versions). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you guys getting this error while updating to laravel 9.0 then remove below line of code from composer.json

```
"fideloper/proxy": "^4.4.1",
```

And run composer update command in terminal

```
composer update
```

Then, change the `use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;` to `use Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies as Middleware;` in a file `app\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies.php file`

Comment: Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#the-assert-deleted-method

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to update the composer

```
composer update
```

and dump the autoload ?

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Yes but the same problem